C++ copy elision when returning a function argument
I'm puzzled as to how this code compiles: (https://godbolt.org/z/hjY4ca4rr)
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(A &&other) = default;

    int x = 0;
};

A f(A a)
{
    a.x = 1;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    f(A());
    return 0;
}

In principle, returning a from f() means copying it to the call-site location, but an A is not copy-able. NRVO copy elision may kick in but:

NRVO is optional, so maybe the code isn't portable (i.e. a compiler that does not employ NRVO will not be able to compile this). This is problematic because if I return std::move(a) to avoid dependency on NRVO, some compilers complain that I screw NRVO.
I don't understand how copy elision works here. Copy elision is based on the premise that the compiler can construct the local variable at a place of its choosing, so it constructs it at the call site location. But here the local is also a function parameter, so the location of it is pre-determined by ABI.

Anyone cares to clarify?

It is not NRVO here, but Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters.

"I don't understand how copy elision works here." — It does not; it cannot work in cases of returning function parameters. See class.copy.elision/1.1 and note that "other than a function parameter". This post nicely describes the logical reasons beyond that: Why is RVO disallowed when returning a parameter?

As Jarod pointed out, it's not doing a copy, but a move, since the compiler knows the variable won't be used afterwards
So it's using the A(A &&other) constructor
To verify it, you can just print out something in the constructor
Also, if you want to disable copy, I recommend you to explicitly write it (and follow the rule of five).
That leads us to this code:
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(A &&other)
    {
        std::cout << "A(A&&)" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A&other) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A &other) = delete;

    A& operator=(A &&other)
    {
        std::cout << "A& operator=(A &&)" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    ~A() = default;

    int x = 0;
};

A f(A a)
{
    a.x = 1;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    f(A());
    return 0;
}

Output:
A(A&&)

So it is definitely calling the move constructor.
